# laravel whereMonth not working in collection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to initialize a collection that I will get from a table but if I use whereMonth on that collection it says that whereMonth does not exist.

I've used whereHas instead of initializing a collection but this becomes a very long code that could still possibly be reduced to a more efficient one.

```
$makati = [];
        $cebu = [];
        $davao = [];

        for($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++){
            $makati[$x-1] = student::with('branch', 'program')
                ->whereHas('branch', function($query){
                    $query->where('name', '!=', 'Language Only');
                })
                ->whereHas('branch', function($query) {
                    $query->where('name', 'Makati');
                })->whereMonth('date_of_signup', $x)->whereYear('date_of_signup', '2019')->count();
        }
```

This is working perfectly fine, but see that I will do the same code for the arrays $cebu and $davao.

```
$student = student::with('branch', 'program')->whereYear('date_of_signup', '2019')->get();
        $student = $student->where('program.name', '!=', 'Language Only');
        $makati = [];
        $cebu = [];
        $davao = [];

        for($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++){
            $makati[$x-1] = $student->whereMonth('date_of_signup', $x);
            info($makati);
        }
```

I've tried this one but this is where the whereMonth error occurs.

the first code actually works but I want to make a shorter and efficient code.

Answer (score 0):

`whereMonth('x', 1)` is a shortcut that generates the SQL `WHERE MONTH(x)=1` . SQL queries aren't generally mapped to the collection even though there is effort made to match collection methods to query builder methods as much as possible. The workaround is:

```
$student = student::with('branch', 'program')->whereYear('date_of_signup', '2019')->get();
$student = $student->where('program.name', '!=', 'Language Only');
$makati = [];
$cebu = [];
$davao = [];

for($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++){
    $makati[$x-1] = $student->filter(function ($value) use ($x) {
         return $value->date_of_signup->month == $x;
    });
    info($makati);
}
```

This assumes that `date_of_signup` is properly casted to a date when retrieved using the `$dates` property in the model.

This is done in your `student` model:

```
 class student extends Model {
     protected $casts = [ 'date_of_signup' => 'date' ]; 
     // rest of model
 }
```

As a sidenote, it's probably more efficient if you do:

```
$student = student::with('branch', 'program')
          ->whereYear('date_of_signup', '2019')
          ->whereHas('program' => function ($query) {
               $query->where('name', '!=', 'Language Only');
          })
          ->get();
```

which will filter the results using an SQL query instead of getting everything and then filtering on the collection

Comment: date_of_signup is actually already a date column in table student. neither solution will not work for me.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? You can set a date column to be casted to a `Carbon` instance in your model

Comment: it says I'm trying to get month of non-object. as for the 2nd solution, where does not work on with. it has to be wherehas.

Comment: Check the update. It shows how to setup casts for your model

Answer (score 0):

```
    $student = student::with('branch', 'program')->whereYear('date_of_signup', '2019');
    $student = $student->where('program.name', '!=', 'Language Only');
    $makati = [];
    $cebu = [];
    $davao = [];

    for($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++){
        $makati[$x-1] = $student->whereMonth('date_of_signup', $x)->get();
        info($makati);
    }
```

Am thinking the whereMonth() method doesn't work on a gotten collection instance but on a query builder instance, so getting the collection makes the method inaccessible. like the code I have copied above, do not get until you are done using all the query builders. I hope this helps.

Comment: what is your response? is the whereMonth still returning an error?

Comment: it's not the whereMonth now, it's because of the get, it's not returning anything if I don't use get in the first line.